# Implementation of "remember me" in code igniter

Tags: security, web-applications, session, codeigniter

How do i remember sessions, even after browser is closed.

is there any alternative than extending expire time of cookies.

i am using code igniter

Answer (score 1):

I implement my version based on [this article](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice). The article explain a concept, security, and how to implement persistent login cookie.

The summary of what I done is:

1. Create a table to hold persistent cookie series and token (series is needed to detect if the cookies got stolen).
2. I write the model to create required cookies (separated from normal CI session).
3. The model also do database
   read/write of the used persistent
   cookies.
4. I integrate this model to existing user model that handle
   normal authentication.
5. When user go to page that need relaxed authentication, without
   normal CI session, but have
   persistent cookie session in his
   browser, my code will recognize it
   since the same series and token also
   stored in the database. The user
   will got a normal CI session, but
   with a flag that this session is
   generated from persistent cookies,
   not from login form.
6. When the user go to 'sensitive' page that demand a CI session
   without persistent flag, then user
   will be logged of, and sent to login
   form (if you use yahoo mail, then it
   similar with that). This usually the
   page where user can do
   add/edit/delete, and see sensitive
   information.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The cookies is that only solution i suspect. As you said, you need to extend the time. However if you wanted to use PHP sessions instead, you to make sessions life longer using php.ini file but i don't think using sessions for this purpose will be a good idea because data of sessions is stored on server rather than individual user.

Thanks

Comment: other thing can be database or even text files. it just matters how you are going to keep track of the users.

Comment: No, you will always need cookies for a persistent session. How else can you match a client with session variables on the server?